# Установка списка отзывов (*.crl) в хранилище компьютера

Tags: c#, сертификат

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста как в C# установить `*.crl` в хранилище компьютера.
Есть код для установки сертификата в корневые сертификаты:

```
private static void InstallRootCertificate(string cerFileName)
{
   X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.AuthRoot, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
   X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(cerFileName);
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
   store.Add(certificate);
   store.Close();
}
```

Но он, по понятным причинам не подходит для crl.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Хотя вопрос был задан очень давно, и уже, возможно, не актуален, все же предложу решение, поскольку проблема интересная. Ее решение может быть полезно, например, когда нужно автоматизировать обновление списков отозванных сертификатов на десятках серверов.</sub>

К сожалению, никаких стандартных средств для решения этой задачи .NET не предоставляет. Придется использовать обертки для `crypt32.dll` и unsafe-код. Ниже приведет пример решения. Его основу составляет класс `CrlFile`, который позволят открыть crl-файл и импортировать его в стандартное хранилище (класс `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store`).

Дополнительная информация:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376011(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://blogs.msdn.com/b/gproano/archive/2005/03/22/400645.aspx?Redirected=true

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

        var crl = new CrlFile(@"d:\tmp\ca\root.crl");
        crl.Import(store, CrlAddDisposition.CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING);
        store.Close();
    }
}

public class CrlFile
{
    // по уму здесь нужна реализация SafeHandle,
    // но чтобы не удлинять код оставим, как есть
    private IntPtr _context;

    private readonly string _file;

    public CrlFile(string file)
    {
        _file = file;
    }

    public bool Import(X509Store store, CrlAddDisposition disp, ref IntPtr storeContext)
    {
        EnsureCrlContext();
        return Crypto32Interop.CertAddCRLContextToStore(store.StoreHandle, _context,
            (uint)disp, storeContext);
    }

    public bool Import(X509Store store, CrlAddDisposition disp)
    {
        var storeContext = IntPtr.Zero;
        return Import(store, disp, ref storeContext);
    }

    private unsafe void EnsureCrlContext()
    {
        if (_context != IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        var context = new IntPtr(Crypto32Interop.CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CRL);

        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_file, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var data = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        bool ret = Crypto32Interop.CryptQueryObject(
                    Crypto32Interop.CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                    data,
                    Crypto32Interop.CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CRL,
                    Crypto32Interop.CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    new IntPtr(&context));

        _context = Crypto32Interop.CertDuplicateCRLContext(context);
        Crypto32Interop.CertFreeCRLContext(context);
        handle.Free();
    }

    ~CrlFile()
    {
        if (_context != IntPtr.Zero)
            Crypto32Interop.CertFreeCRLContext(_context);
    }
}

public static class Crypto32Interop
{
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CTL = 2;
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CRL = 3;

    public const uint CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE = 1;

    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY = 1;
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BASE64_ENCODED = 2;
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED = 3;

    public const uint CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CRL = (1 << (int)CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CRL);
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CTL = (1 << (int)CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_CTL);
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY = (1 << (int)CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BINARY);
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BASE64_ENCODED = (1 << (int)CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_BASE64_ENCODED);
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED = (1 << (int)CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED);
    public const uint CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL =
       (CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY |
       CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BASE64_ENCODED |
       CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ASN_ASCII_HEX_ENCODED);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CertDuplicateCRLContext(IntPtr pCrlContext);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CertFreeCRLContext(IntPtr pCrlContext);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CertAddCRLContextToStore(
        [In]    IntPtr hCertStore,
        [In]    IntPtr pCrlContext,
        [In]    uint dwAddDisposition,
        [Out]   IntPtr ppStoreContext);

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool CryptQueryObject(
         [In]       uint dwObjectType,
         [In]       IntPtr pvObject,
         [In]       uint dwExpectedContentTypeFlags,
         [In]       uint dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags,
         [In]       uint dwFlags,
         [Out]      IntPtr pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
         [Out]      IntPtr pdwContentType,
         [Out]      IntPtr pdwFormatType,
         [In, Out]  IntPtr phCertStore,
         [In, Out]  IntPtr phMsg,
         [In, Out]  IntPtr ppvContext);
}

public enum CrlAddDisposition : uint
{
    CERT_STORE_ADD_NEW = 1,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_USE_EXISTING = 2,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING = 3,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_ALWAYS = 4,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING_INHERIT_PROPERTIES = 5,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_NEWER = 6,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_NEWER_INHERIT_PROPERTIES = 7,
}
```

Comment: Ого! А можно брать адрес у `context` без `fixed`?

Comment: @VladD, IntPtr - структура, поэтому ее экземпляр создается в стеке. Для стековой переменной в пределах функции можно брать адрес без fixed.

Comment: Ну да, но это достаточно хрупкое предположение, т. к. функция может превратиться в итератор или `async`-функцию, и переменные уйдут в хип.

Comment: @VladD сопрограммы не могут быть unsafe, компилятор ругается

Comment: Тем не менее, это хрупкое предположение. В стандарте C# вовсе не упоминается стек, так что конформная имплементация (например, на системе, в которой нет понятия стека) имеет право положить все переменные в кучу.

Comment: Конечно, ответ в любом случае использует P/Invoke, так что он ориентирован на Windows. Я обычно в случаях, когда правильность кода не самоочевидна, оставляю развёрнутый комментарий с изложением причин, или делаю код очевидно правильным (в зависимости от того, что короче/эффективнее).